# Import was not found or had errors

Tags: maven, apache-spark, protobuf-java, velox

I was executing the following command.

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dcheckstyle.skip -Pbackends-velox -Dbuild_protobuf=OFF -Dbuild_cpp=ON -Dbuild_velox=On -Dvelox_home=${VELOX_HOME} -Dbuild_arrow=OFF -Dcompile_velox=ON
```

Then I got the following error message:

```
spark311_2/tools/build/velox_ep/velox/substrait/proto/substrait/type_expressions.proto
google/protobuf/any.proto: File not found.
substrait/extensions/extensions.proto:6:1: Import "google/protobuf/any.proto" was not found or had errors
```

But I can find the google/protobuf/any.proto is located under those two path:

```
./build/velox_ep/_build/release/_deps/protobuf-src/src/google/protobuf/any.proto
./build/velox_ep/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/any.proto
```

Furthermore, the file extensions.proto which is trying to import the "google/protobuf/any.proto" is in the following directory:

```
./build/velox_ep/velox/substrait/proto/substrait/extensions/extensions.proto
```

Also, I am using the Ubuntu machine.

Could anyone have any idea about how to fix this error?
Thanks a lot.